# time complexity of shortest job first algorithm when jobs are non preemptive

Tags: algorithm, operating-system

Shortest job first algorithm is implemented through min heap data structure.
Then what will be the time complexity of SJF algorithm?

I have read it somewhere that it is n*2*log n which is equal to n log n . Please explain how.
(Sorry if the question is too easy.I am new to it.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Both the [Insert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Insert) and the [Extract-Min](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Extract) operations have a running time of `O(log n)`. There are `n` tasks and each task has to be inserted to the heap and later extracted from the heap, resulting in a running time of `O(n log n)`.

The reason `Insert` has a running time of `O(log n)` is that when inserting we first add the new task to the heap final position. This does not necessarily maintain the [heap property](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/minheapprop.html), as the priotiy of the new task might be better (having a smaller key) than the priority of its parent. This is why the `Insert` operation involves the [Heapify-Up procedure](https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/spring05/cps130/lectures/littman.lectures/lect08/node17.html) whose purpose is to restore the heap order. The `Heapify-Up` procedure has a running time of `O(log n)`.

The reason `Extract-Min` has a running time of `O(log n)` is that in the `Extract-Min` operation we first delete the root of the heap (the first task) and then move the last task to the first position (that is, replacing the root with the task residing in the last position). As this possibly violates the heap property, the `Extract-Min` involves the execution of the [Heapify-Down procedure](https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/spring05/cps130/lectures/littman.lectures/lect08/node16.html). The `Heapify-Down` procedure also has a running time of `O(log n)`.

Comment: Insertion requires that you add the new item at the end of the heap and move it up. Deletion replaces the root with the last item and moves it down the heap. Neither operation requires the full heapify procedure that you link to.

Comment: @JimMischel, thanks for the comment. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Non-preemptive sjf can be done in O(nlogn) time complexity using segment tree.
Take the inputs of processes in struct and sort the struct array according to
arrival time. Now, we will use segment tree to find the range minimum burst time and corresponding process id which will take **2*logn** for query and update both.